# Consideration of previously created reward function in AWS Deep Racer

Tags: amazon-web-services, reinforcement-learning

Suppose I create a reward fn. A and train my model. Then, I clone the model and make changes to the reward fn. (let's say reward fn. B) and train it. So does the final model have learnings from reward fn. A and B or does it forget the learning from fn. A and only get trained from reward fn. B?

Comment: I also did not know the answer but you could clone the model trained by A and start a second training with same function A. Now if your progress (percentage track completion) is already high like you end your first training it's likely that the modell keeps the training. If it's low like in the beginning of first training it shows that it forgot the training data.  Did you found out in the mean time @CuriousHash?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deepracer/latest/developerguide/awsracerdg.pdf

> Clone a trained model continue training for improved performances.

it should continue with training.
I also tried know to clone and to continue with unchanged reward function and the results are in the beginning already much better than with first tries.

But I could imagine if you change your function the trained neural network behind will adapt more and more to your new reward funtion B with every new episode.